# How to prevent the admin customer form when click on save and continue button with Jquery Script?

Tags: jquery, magento2

I need to place custom validation in magento2 admin customer form.

I have tried with following code , getting alert but its redirecting and saving the customer.

```
$("#save_and_continue,#save").on('click',function(e){
   //alert('test');
   return false;
   // e.preventDefault();
});
```

Please help me to solve this.

thank you

Comment: Why do you comment `e.preventDefault()` ? This line should do the job

Comment: Hi Antonin , I have uncommented still getting same issue

Comment: Try to put the line before your return false;

Comment: If its a submit button, then it can have special conditions, You should bind it to the `submit` event. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985196/return-false-is-not-working-in-my-submit-click

Comment: @Rana, Do you get the answer of it> If yes, please post the answer. I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :

```
$("#save_and_continue,#save").on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('test');
   return false;
});
```

You should put e.preventDefault() before returning something in your function because return close your function so the e.preventDefault() will not be executed.

hope this help

Comment: thank you , I have tried with that also still getting same issue

Comment: Here is the code
$("#save_and_continue,#save").on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault() 
   e.stopPropagation();;
   alert('test');
   return false;
});

Magento 2 admin customer form is submitting based on onclick not with form submit.

Comment: If it's based on a button onClick, you should probably find something in the code that provide this action (redirect), you should maybe cut it or something to prevent this action

Comment: thank you for your comment , but we can't change the default magento functionality.Its better to write custom script instead of using core

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the onclick in the markup as it would fire before your click listener added from JQuery.

```
$('<your form selector>').on('click', function(event) {
 if(isn't a valid submission){
    event.preventDefault()
 }else{
    // add onclick event code here!!!
 }

}
```

& `event.stopPropagation()` if you dnt wan't it to bubble up. And, do note that it is no longer considered good practice to `return false` as runtime error would prevent returning.

Comment: Magento 2 admin customer form is submitting based on onclick event not with form submit.
here is my revert code
$("#save_and_continue,#save").on('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert('test');
         e.stopPropagation();
         return false;
        });

With e.preventDefault() also not able to stop the form

Comment: Can you give me the HTML markup for this, if its just a button then why would it submit?

Comment: Here is the button tag
<button id="save_and_continue" title=" Save and Continue Edit" type="button" class="action- scalable save ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="location.href = 'http://local.mysite.com/';" data-ui-id="save-and-continue-button" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">
    <span> Save and Continue Edit</span>
</span></button>

In magento onclick functionality working different, please check magento functionality  once and help me to solve this bro

Comment: `onclick="location.href = 'local.mysite.com/';" ` this attaches another event listener to the click event.  `onclick` would execute before your method and hence you are unable to prevent submission. Try to add this code into your custom handler and remove the onclick attribute.